# Querying with model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Rails app has 2 models: Cost and Account.
My Cost model has an amount column and a reference to the Account model (account_id).
Now I want to make a query finding the total amount for a specific account. Something like this:

```
Cost.where(account_id: 1).sum(:amount)
```

And it gives me the exact result. How can I change the query using the account name attribute instead of the account id attribute in order to get a similar expression:

```
Cost.where(account_name: "salaries").sum(:amount)
```

In this way I dont have to look for the account_id. Of course my Cost model doesn't have any account_name attribute but just an account_id reference. Is there a way to infer from the account_id the account_name? How should I write the correct query?

Comment: Did you try something like`Account.includes(:costs).where(account_name: "salaries").sum(:amount)` ?

Comment: I've tried but it didn't work. After I checked my model once again and found out that I didn't set the account association properly (has many :costs). Now it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `joins`

```
Cost.joins(:account).where(accounts: { name: "salaries" }).sum(:amount)
```

**Note:** In this query, I am assuming name of table for account model is `accounts`

**Edit:**

Query with date range

```
    Cost
      .joins(:account)
      .where(accounts: { name: "salaries" })
      .where('created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', from_date, to_date) 
      .sum(:amount)
```

**Note:**  `from_date` and `to_date` has to be `Date` objects

Ex: `from_date = "1-3-2017".to_date`

Comment: Thanks. It works.  Yes the table for the account model is accounts. What if I want to add dates range? Like: give me all the costs from 1-3-2017 to 31-3-2017 associated to the salaries account?

Comment: Updated answer with date query